# How shall I populate my RecyclerView asynchronously?

Tags: android

**Problem**

My RecyclerView displays elements with photos. Every photo is being downloaded from the Internet which may take up to few seconds. Hence, I try to avoid blocking the UI thread and I pass the work to a Handler, however, due to RecyclerView's recycling behavior, it shows the images improperly.

**This is how it looks like:**

Loads image 1 to list item 1.

Loads image 2 to list item 2.

I scroll down.

Loads image 3 to list item 20.

Loads image 4 to list item 21.

Loads image 4 to list item 20.

Loads image 5 to list item 21.

At the end everything is ok, but during the loading process, RecyclerView recycles the ViewHolders with the wrong images!

**My code**

```
mHandler.post(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            final Uri image = complexFetchingFunction();

            activity.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    try {
                        holder.imageView.setImageURI(image);
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            });
        }
    });
```

**End**

Handler works on a separate thread. That's sure. 
I know all these things happen, because I load the images asynchronously and RecyclerView doesn't like it, but otherwise it's painfully slow.

Does anyone have a solution?

Comment: handlers work on the context of the thread whom instatiate them. If the handler was instatiated on the ui thread, it will run on the ui thread

Comment: It doesn't run on the UI thread. The initialization of the Handler is a bit longer.

Comment: What method and class contains the code shown here?

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest using [Glide](https://github.com/bumptech/glide). It will load the images asynchronously for you, and cache them.

As an example, you'd use it as such

```
Glide.with(context)
            .load("your_url")
            .into(your_imageview);
```

Comment: Yeah, but fetching the Uri from the Internet takes a lot of time. I have to put the fetching code into a Handler/Thread/Whatever runnable. Take a look at the code above.

Answer (score 1):

From android document **[Processing Bitmaps Off the UI Thread](http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/process-bitmap.html)**

But I recommend you to use **[UIL](https://github.com/nostra13/Android-Universal-Image-Loader)** library to load images in recyclerview. This is most popular and efficient library, easy to integrate.

Features :

Multithread image loading (async or sync)

Wide customization of ImageLoader's configuration (thread executors, downloader, decoder, memory and disk cache, display image options, etc.)

Many customization options for every display image call (stub images, caching switch, decoding options, Bitmap processing and displaying, etc.)

Image caching in memory and/or on disk (device's file system or SD card)
Listening loading process (including downloading progress)

For more details visit https://github.com/nostra13/Android-Universal-Image-Loader

You can also try **[GLIDE](https://github.com/bumptech/glide)**. Glide supports GIF images also.

You can compare image loader libraries **[here](http://www.unknownerror.org/opensource/square/picasso/q/stackoverflow/29363321/picasso-v-s-imageloader-v-s-fresco-vs-glide)**

Comment: It seems like you misunderstood me. I don't have problem with the image loading. The issue comes from the delay before loading the image and RecyclerView recycling. Cause the downloading requires a few seconds(!), I must do it in another thread. After that I call runOnUiThread from the separate thread and load the image.

Comment: I guess this is what I was searching for.

Answer (score 1):

Use Glide library. It is the library recommended by Google and also used in various google apps like Google Photos, Hangout etc.